# Do cloud messaging topic subscriptions persist?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I subscribe my firebase user to a cloud messaging topic with         `firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(groups.id)` , does that subscription persist when the app get's closed?

And if there are no subscribers to a topic, does the topic still exist? I want to send notifications to a topic where the topic is the id of the group the users are in. But when the group get's deleted should I manually delete the topic aswell?

And if they persist is there a way to find out if the user is subscribed to them? So I can update the UI to show that the user is subscribed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Yes. Topic subscriptions are stored on Google's servers, so persist when the app is not active. In fact, that is key in allowing the use of topics to deliver push messages when the app isn' running.

There is no need to maintain topics yourself, nor to check if they exist. If you want to send a message to a topic, you can just do so. If you want to subscribe to/unsubscribe from a topic, you can also just do that.

There is no public API that allows you to determine what tokens are subscribed to a topic, nor to determine what topics a token is subscribed to. If you need this, you'll have to maintain the necessary mappings yourself.